# LibGdx, Render Counting integer on the screen

Tags: java, libgdx

Now the program can count number until 31, I like to make it to render the `count` integer variable on screen. I tried `batch.draw(Integer.toString(count));` and also tried `font.draw(batch, Integer.toString(count), 25, 160);` both gave me error(Syntax errors) in JAVA. please give me some advice. Thank You~

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class Prac1 extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private float w,h,tw,th =0;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Sprite img;
    private int count;


    @Override
    public void create () {
        w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(w, h);
        camera.position.set(w/2, h/2, 0);
        camera.update();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("iceCream.png")));
        tw = img.getWidth();
        th = img.getHeight();
        img.setBounds(camera.position.x - (tw/2), camera.position.y - (th/2),tw,th);
        count=0;


        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter(){

            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

                if(img.getBoundingRectangle().contains(screenX, screenY) && count<=31) 
                    System.out.println(count++);

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        img.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: when you say it does not work what do you mean? is the count just not showing or its not compiling at all?

Comment: oh yeah it was lack of information, it was syntax error. Do you know how the variable `count` show up on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to declare a bitmap font and intialise it in your create method (it looks like you forgot to do that):

```
private BitmapFont font;
private SpriteBatch batch;

public void create() {        
    batch = new SpriteBatch();    
    font = new BitmapFont();
    font.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

@Override
public void render() {        
    batch.begin();
    font.draw(batch, String.valueOf(count), 200, 200); //you can change the position as you like
    batch.end();
}
```

and replace

```
System.out.println(count++);
```

with `count++`